# awakeFromNib calling every scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Well, I'm using UITableView to show my TextFields, I have 25 Rows.

I want to show inside this fields the data come from my database, for this I use the following code below:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSMutableArray *arrayFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    arrayFields = [SelectDB initWithTable:@"myFields" from:1 database:@"databases/bcd.sqlite" times:@"databases/times"];

    self.textField1.text = arrayFields[1];
    self.textField2.text = arrayFields[2];
    ......


}
```

this code works very well and put the text inside my fields, but is **SLOW** when I scroll my table.

When the table scrolls up or down the method awakeFromNib is called, and again I need to select data in database and change the field value.

To try to solve this problem I move the SELECT function to a background Thread and the UI commands to main thread using this code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        // Perform async operation
        // Call your method/function here
        // Example:
        // NSString *result = [anObject calculateSomething];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    // Update UI
                    // Example:
                    // self.myLabel.text = result;
                });
    });
```

This is the best optimized way to solve this problem? Have another way more simple and optimized?

```
EDIT
```

Using GCD in this case my app sometimes crash sometimes no....

```
EDIT 2
```

Well I can solve this problem moving that code (inside awakeFromNib) to cellForRowAtIndexPath, and the slow STOPED!

But I find another problem! Lets try to change the text inside my first textfield lets put the text **"Hello World"**, great, now lets scroll down to the last field and change his text...lets go back to the first field and the "Hello World" disappear!

Working with UITable is more complicated that I imagine....

Comment: `- (void)awakeFromNib` is the method of custom cell?

Comment: Why do you SELECT each time for each cell? Why not SELECT all data to an array. Then get data for each cell in that array?

Comment: You're doing this completely wrong. Cells are reused; they have no data of their own. The place to associate data with a cell is `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. Throw your `awakeFromNib` implementation out the window and start over.

Comment: @anhtu I do this now!, See my edit post (EDIT 2)

Comment: @matt right matt!, see my edited post! I have one more problem now...

Comment: But that just means that your implementation of `cellForRow` is _wrong_. Well, you haven't shown it, so at this point your question is meaningless. I suggest you delete it, do some thinking, and ask a new question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it changes faster than Liberace changes suits.

Answer (score 0):

Your cell is a view; let it be one!

```
UITableViewController
```

^^ He asks for a data source and a cell to display. He shouldn't know about the database at all.

Load **all** records into an array in the view controller (once) and supply the info when configuring the cell.

DB lookups are very expensive. And putting the work on a background thread is masking the problem sorry, as your data increases you will start having empty cells

Answer (score 0):

That is why `dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier` is used in `UITableView` delegate method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` keeping data ready to be rendered when cells are asked for.

Here is what I would recommend doing.

1. Move your DB fetch call in `loadView` of your view controller: `[SelectDB initWithTable:@"myFields" from:1 database:@"databases/bcd.sqlite" times:@"databases/times"];`. **Calling DB with every cell rendering is a crime!**
2. Save the DB data locally in global variable.
3. Implement `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and set the cell text fields data in there.

Answer (score 0):

In your case maybe I would try a different approach. Maybe getting the needed records in the DB and putting it inside an array in my View Controller. After using it in the UITableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

However you can go further by making a model class to map each of your BD records and filling the array using a loop:

```
// understanding self.arrayFields as the array of all the records from the DB
NSMutableArray *mappedRecords = [@[] mutableCopy];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < self.arrayFields.count; i++)
{
    CustomClass *object = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
    object.field1 = self.arrayFields[i][0];
    object.field2 = self.arrayFields[i][0];
    [mappedRecords addObject:object];
}
```

I think this approach is better. Additionally you can isolate the filling of each cell from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, to the cell itself by creating a method inside your UITableViewCell object like `configureCellWithObject:object`. Your datasource method will look cleanest.

**About EDIT 2**

This is because of the reusing of the cells. When the tableview retrieve a new cell to reuse, it changes its content with the new object at that indexPath. You have to modify the content of the object at that point to avoid the tableView to modify your content when scrolling.